# Creating dynamic json

Tags: json, go

I need to create dynamic json i.e whose key value varies, below mentioned is the json

```
[{"email":"xxx@gmail.com","location":{"set":"Redmond"},"fname":{"set":"xxxxx"},"clicked_time":{"set":"zz"},"domain":{"add":"ttt"}},{"email":"zzz@gmail.com","location":{"set":"Greece"},"fname":{"set":"zzzzz"},"clicked_time":{"set":"zzz"},"domain":{"add":"zxxxx"}}]
```

I tried using below code:

```
rows := []map[string]string{}
if i > 0 {
    row := make(map[string]string)
    for j:=0;j<len(record);j++ {
        key := header[j]
        value := record[j]
        row[key] = value  
    }   
    rows = append(rows, row)
}
```

How may I add set to location and add to domain to create a nested structure as map can have only one type string or nested structure?

Comment: Make a map of type `map[string]interface{}`

Comment: Thanks , can you give me some implementation on the example as i am very new with go to work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I have missed the point a little here, but I am not seeing why this is so dynamic in a way that can't be handled by a struct and the json unmarshal method.

Please see the following for an example

https://play.golang.org/p/8nrO36HQGhy

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)


type (

    Details struct {

        Email           string  `json:"email"`
        Location        Entry   `json:"location"`
        FName           Entry   `json:"fname"`
        ClickedTime     Entry   `json:"clicked_time"`
        Domain          Entry   `json:"domain"`
    }

    Entry struct {
        Set             string  `json:"set"`
        Add                     string  `json:"add"`
    }

)


func main() {


    d := []byte(`[{
        "email": "xxx@gmail.com",
        "location": {
            "set": "Redmond"
        },
        "fname": {
            "set": "xxxxx"
        },
        "clicked_time": {
            "set": "zz"
        },
        "domain": {
            "add": "ttt"
        }
    }, {
        "email": "zzz@gmail.com",
        "location": {
            "set": "Greece"
         },
        "fname": {
            "set": "zzzzz"
        },
        "clicked_time": {
            "set": "zzz"
        },
        "domain": {
            "add": "zxxxx"
        }
    }]`)


    x := []Details{}
    _ = json.Unmarshal(d, &x)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", x)
}
```